# Splitting strings - for a calculation

Tags: python, string, split

I want to create a calculator with several functions. When the user inputs something such as "ADD3, DIVIDE4" it will output the answer. So I believe I will have to split the string to work on each part individually. 
So far all I can find is

```
    numb= input("What is your first numb")
    calc = input("What is your calculation")
    calc.split(', ')
```

But I don't know how to work on each section once it has been split.
So for example if the first is numb = 5 and then its 'calc = ADD3, SUB4' the program will output 4. But then so when it gets more complicated with more calculations and things like DIVIDE it will still work.
Thank you

Comment: If you want us to debug your code, you should provide it. Otherwise there is nothing we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through calc Items. In the loop use a Switch case to find out the Operation and do the calculation.

edit: refer to this [link](https://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html) for switch case implementation in python.

Comment: There is not `switch case` construct in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
numb = input("What is your first numb")
calc = input("What is your calculation")
ops = calc.split(', ')

for op in ops:
    if op.lower().startswith('add'):
        number = float(op[3:])
        numb += number
    elif op.lower().startswith('sub'):
        number = float(op[3:])
        numb -= number
    elif op.lower().startswith('divide'):
        number = float(op[6:])
        numb /= number
print(numb)
```

So what you do here is the following:

- Determine the operation ( op.lower().startswith(operation) ), .lower() makes it case insensitive
- Find the number by selecting the rest of the string using string slicing (op[3:] or op[6:] )
- Perform the operation on numb

Note: This does the operations in the order they are inputted, not in the PEMDAS order of operations!

Comment: Thank you for this